# SvelteKit: Why is {Math.random()} updated twice when reloading page?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I have noticed the following surprising behaviour. If you have a template with the following code and you reload the page, it updates twice:

```
{Math.random()}
```

Can anyone explain why? Just curious.

To reproduce, create Svelte Kit Skeleton project and add the string above in +page.svelte.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the page is first server-side rendered, so the component is first rendered on the server, and `Math.random()` is called once there, and then the HTML code for that is sent back to the client. Then the client renders its own instance of the component and shows that one instead, so `Math.random()` would yield another number now, and this number is soon shown on the screen.

Comment: Let me repeat, what happens is this:
1) The page loads and I see the first number
2) I hit Cmd+R and the number changes
3) The page finishs loading and I see a third number

It may be related to server + client side rendering, but either I don't understand what you mean or it does not sound convincing.

Comment: I don't see how any of that goes against what I'm suggesting. You do undersand that `Math.random()` will yield a new number each time the component is rendered, right? Per your observations: 1. Client side rendered. 2. Server side rendered. 3. Client side rendered. [The docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/page-options) says a **little** about it.